# C# Updating Dataset and DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, tableadapter, datagridviewcolumn

So im trying to have a DataGridView that is connected to a database, with some text boxes and a button to add more data to the DB. I can have it update the table, but cant get it to properly update the Database.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ParametSampleApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tableTableAdapter1.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Table);

        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow newUserRow = database1DataSet.Tables["Table"].NewRow();

            newUserRow["FirstName"] = txtFName.Text;
            newUserRow["LastName"] = txtLName.Text;
            newUserRow["PostCode"] = txtPostcode.Text;
            newUserRow["OperatingSystem"] = txtOS.Text;

            database1DataSet.Tables["Table"].Rows.Add(newUserRow);

            this.tableTableAdapter1.Update(this.database1DataSet.Table);

        }
    }
}
```

If you need a ZIP of the whole project to get an easier understanding i can easily upload and send.

It may be worth noting that i used the DataGridView GUI to set up the connection so my DataSet, BindingSource and TableTableAdaper were automatically created aswell.

Comment: what do you mean with "can't get it to update properly"? Do you get an exception? Remains the database empty? Is there a value you don't expect? ...

Comment: When the tableadapter.Update is called, it looks for modified rows, and for each modified row, calls the UpdateCommand object on the adapter, passing the fields for the datarow in - you may want to check what is in the SQL for your UpdateCommand object.

Comment: Thomas, i meant that the data itself would not go back into the Database, it would show on the table, but not in the actual Database.                                Rick, good to know, but the code you see is all i have added, there are no external classes and im not too sure where to find the UpdateCommand object. If needed i can chuck the whole project on GitHub to let you have a more thorough look.

Comment: Check that "tableTableAdapter1.InsertCommand.CommandText" contains an SQL INSERT Command. If not, your adapter is not correctly initialized for update. Did you add the instruction "SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);" after TableAdapter creation?

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you are looking for but if not sorry I couldn't help.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

{

bindingSource1.EndEdit();    
DataTable dt = (DataTable)bindingSource1.DataSource;   
tableTableAdapter1.Update(dt); 

}
```